# Unit Testing Controller to Check That Render Is Called

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rspec

All I want to do is test that the controller is actually calling `render`.

#### Note:

I don't care about the output in this test, so I don't want to check the `response.body` or `assert_template`, etc.  I just want to make sure the method of `render` is being sent to the controller.

#### controller action:

```
  def create
    render json: { error: "some error" }, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
```

#### spec:

Stubbing out the authorization callbacks:

```
before do
  allow(AuthenticateRequest).to receive(:call).and_return(true)
  allow_any_instance_of(CanCan::ControllerResource).to receive(:load_resource).and_return(nil)
end
```

This is literally the only expectation the spec so there is nothing conflicting.
    it "renders error in json" do
      args = {
        json:   { error: "some error" },
        status: :unprocessable_entity
      }

```
  expect(controller).to receive(:render).with(args)
  post :create, user: { upload: upload }
end

# rspec spec/controllers
# FAILURE:
expected: ({:json=>{:error=>"some error"}, :status=>:unprocessable_entity})
got: (no args)
```

Here is possible clue of me doing something wrong.  This is what happens when I remove the argument expectation:

```
it "renders error in json" do
  expect(controller).to receive(:render) # no args expectation
  post :create, user: { upload: upload } # called two times??
end

# rspec spec/controllers
# FAILURE:
expected: 1 time with any arguments
received: 2 times with any arguments
```

What am I missing here?

#### Update:

Here's another try.  Yet another error:

```
it "renders error in json" do
  expect(controller).to receive(:render).with(
    foo:    { error: "some error" },
    status: :unprocessable_entity
  ).at_least(:once)

  post :create, price_patch_upload: { upload: "upload" }, format: :json
end
```

**Result**:
[image: first error]

...but when I change the test to match what is being expected. Notice the `at_least(:once)` expectation.  Even if controller is rendering twice, you would think this would pass:

```
it "renders error in json" do
  expect(controller).to receive(:render).with(
    json:   { error: "some error" },
    status: :unprocessable_entity
  ).at_least(:once)

  post :create, price_patch_upload: { upload: "upload" }, format: :json
end
```

**Result**:
[image: next error]

???

Comment: Do you perhaps have `before_action` in your controller or in your `ApplicationController` that possibly renders twice? Or if you have "hidden" `before_action` like maybe a gem that authenticates or authorises or something?

Comment: ahh yes, good point.  Yes I do.  The application controller calls on `authenticate_request` and the user controller has CanCan's `load_and_authorize_resource`.  I thought I stubbed out those methods though.  I will update question for reference.

Comment: I just reproduced the same problem as yours. My current guess is that it renders twice, because under the hood rails also still calls `render` (even though I thought it would not do so anymore when `render` is already manually called). So far, all of my attempts are not working. The only quick solution at the moment is to `expect(response.body).to eq {error: 'some error'}` and `expect(response).to have_http_status(:unprocessable_entity)` and `expect(response.content_type).to eq 'application/json'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following is tested and should now work:

```
expect(controller).to receive(:render).with(args).and_call_original
post :create, user: { upload: upload }
```

`.and_call_original` is needed because mocking `render` will then make Rails think that `render` still is not yet called as whatever underlying it is mocked, thereby calling it twice.

`.and_call_original` will let the mocked method do what it does, and run normally.

Comment: You sir, are a scholar and a gentlemen.  Thank you!  Saved me from pulling out even more hair.

Comment: @binarymason no worries. Glad to be of help :)